# Make a new user in SQL developer to create a new database

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to create a new user and a database but when Oracle SQL developer says that I have insufficient permissions.

I have searched for hours in google and found a way to create a new user in the HR database through the SQL Command Line. So, I see the new user in Oracle SQL developer but it wont let me create any tables.

When I try to create a table it says 
"`Error - the new TABLE TableTest was not found in the database.`"

and if I try to create it again it says
"`Name TableTest is already in use.`"...

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to create a new user with own tables. In this case you want to create a new scheme, not a new database.

First, you must create a user USER1 from a user USER0 having privileges to create users:

```
USER0> create user USER1 identified by PASSWORD;
```

Second, assign system privileges to user:

```
USER0> grant create table to USER1;
```

Third, log in with USER1 in SQL Developer and create table:

```
USER1> create table TableTest (column1 varchar2(10));
```

Then, you can query this table:

```
USER1> select * from TableTest;
```

By last, if you want to query TableTest from USER0, you must give a privilege from USER1:

```
USER1> grant select on TableTest to USER0;
```

Log in with USER0 and display the query:

```
USER0> select * from USER1.TableTest;
```

Regards